# How to loop through an Array Object in Github action event

Tags: github-actions

I would like to get all the labels added in a PR and filter out specific labels with the prefix `project:`. For achieving this I tried accessing the `github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name`. In the shell, I'm trying to loop through this array to filter out just the label that I require.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Get Project name from labels
    if: ${{ contains(join(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name,','),'project:') }}
    run: | 
      x="${{ toJson(github.event.pull_request.labels) != '[]' }}"
      labels=${{ github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name }}
      project=""
      for label in ${labels[*]}; do
        echo $label
        if [[ $label == project:* ]]; then
          project=$(echo "$label" | sed 's/^project://')
        fi
      done    
      echo $project
    shell: bash
```

But no matter how I try, I'm just getting the output of `github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name` as `Array`. How can I access this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be much simpler with GitHub CLI's [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```yaml
- name: Get project names from labels
  env:
    PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  shell: bash
  run: |
    gh pr view \
      --json labels \
      --jq '.labels[].name | select(startswith("project:")) | sub("project:";"")' \
      "$PR_NUMBER"
```

Here's the sample output for a [test PR](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/pull/13) with labels `project:test1` and `project:test2` among others:

[image: gh pr view]