# how to put a label matching a pattern into a variable for later use within the job

Tags: github-actions

I want the PRs labeled with the following pattern `I18n <product-id> <lang-tag>`, i.e. `I18n 1234 de_DE` to run a job which extracts that label and set two variables: `productID` and `langTag`.
The two variables will be used as parameters of a script the actions executes:

Something like:

```yaml
jobs:
    checkI18NTokensJob:
        if: startsWith(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'i18n')
        container: xxx
        env:
            FORCE_OUTPUT_MISSING_TRANSLATION_TO_FILE: true
        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: yarn
            - name: extract the parameters from the matching label
              # how to do it? 
            - name: Check i18n tokens
              run: <my-script-here> <product-id> <lang tag>
```

is that possible?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701641/how-to-loop-through-an-array-object-in-github-action-event. It uses GitHub CLI's command [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view) to retrieve labels. You can modify it according to your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally used an expansion variable along with `toJson`, which set an environament variable that a script can easily read and parse. Then, I can output the wanted result to `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`:

i.e.

```yaml
jobs:
    generate-matrix:
        ...
        env:
            GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name) }}
        steps:
            - name: set-matrix
              id: set-matrix
              run: echo "$(${PWD}/.github/workflows/scripts/generate-check-i18n-matrix.sh)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```