# Get a label after a PR was merged

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's say I have a PR with `some` label.

Can I get the value of the label from the PR in an action - that is run on push - after the PR was merged?

Or the more general question is whether I can pass somehow an information from a PR being merged to the action that was triggered after this PR was merged?

Comment: IIUC, you want to extract a label while the current workflow is running and then use it somehow (maybe, pass to another action for further processing). Yes, you can do this. Here's an example with GitHub CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75703276/7670262.

Comment: Also, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows.